# How do I get rid of these bees/wasps in my sunroom?

Tags: pest-control, removal

Found this in my sunroom this morning:

[image]

It's hard to see (I didn't want too get too close) but the bees are *really* strange looking - very long almost like 2 bees connected in a row.

I know there's Wasp Killer, Hornet Killer, General Bee Killer, etc. Want to make sure I use the right product that kills them dead.

Comment: Looks like a mud wasp. Wasp and hornet spray will usually spray a stream up to 10 feet rather than a misty fog.

Comment: Not A Bee. Please help save our indigenous bee population and domesticated bees. Your food supply depends on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a mud dauber wasp nest. Any wasp spray from the local hardware store should take care of it.

Answer (score 5):

That is a very small nest. Since the sunroom is indoors, I would not recommend using wasp spray, especially if the label on the can recommends against indoor use.

**1)** They'll be back if you do not plug their entry way into your sunroom.

**2)** Insecticide spray is not necessary.  Just knock the nest down with a broom *handle* or similar, then leave the sunroom, closing the door behind you.  The few that might be in the nest will calm down and may exit the sunroom to the outdoors.  If not, they can killed with a flyswatter or kitchen towel.

Comment: The better option. We had Jerry Builders for the construction of our house. They didn't caulk the grooves in the T-111 siding when they applied the trim and Mud Daubers nested all round the top plate perimeter. I removed probably 250 lbs. of mud nest when I cleared the attic to reinsulate. 10 tubes of caulk and that will never happen again. vs. a continuous poison fog every spring? Keeping them out in the first place is better for your health. And it keeps the Carpenter Bees, Ants, Mud Daubers, Paper Wasps and Yellow Jacket Hornets out...